# Tables being affected by current transactions in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

We are designing a Web-based application with Oracle backend for Conference Room reservation. Also - we have decided to use optimistic locking because we expect the number of collisions to be on the lower side.

Now - in case of optimistic locking, there is always a possibility of "Data Already Modified by Somebody Else" scenario.

And our UI involves quite a few fields to be entered. And displaying a message such as "Data has already been modified" is not a pleasant experience for the end-user; especially after he/she has entered say 15+ field.

What I am contemplating is displaying "Collision Probability" when the end user starts his/her UI session based upon first few entries he/she has entered on the UI.

This CP (collision probability) will be dynamically calculated by taking into account the database sessions which are in progress against given table/columns.

For example - if both Person A and Person B are viewing information for Conference Room X - then both will be shown a higher CP (collision probability).

In such case - either of them can decide to wait few seconds. This will be better than re-entering all the data.

Now my question : In Oracle, is there a way to determine which sessions are going against which tables and ROWID ?

Comment: No Oracle doesn't support *dirty reads*. But you can implement DIY solution. Additionaly to the *update* `VERSION` column, which is updated on each commit and signals *the update from other session* you set up a *last select timestamp*  column that helps you to estimate the probability that the record is in pending transaction from other session.

Comment: @MarmiteBomber - so you'd update a record every time somebody selected it? Indeed, if the application selects a list of available rooms that would be multiple updates. That seems rather heavy.

Comment: No need for that @APC. I'd manage to update the record exact at the time when the user *choose a room* as you describe it in your answer. So we are following not a complete different strategy. Only your `pessimistic` approach will *suck* if there are users that *choose a room* and than *decide to take their lunch*.  Of course the *reading update*  doesn't change the optimistic `VERSION` column. BTW I never use this approach, but on my short list is a test of it to see if there is a statistical improvement using this *last read timestamp*.

Answer (score 0):

> "our UI involves quite a few fields to be entered."

This seems like the sort of problem which could be solved by better flow. Minimise the number of fields a user needs to enter before they can get a list of available suitable rooms. When they choose a room, use pessimistic locking to ensure nobody else can snatch the room while they are completing the booking application. Stash a copy of the initial fields so they can re-run the original query if they change their mind.

Of course, this means maintaining a session and handling state, and we all know web applications suck at that. Which is a way of saying that we often use web technologies when they aren't suited to the application we're writing.